# Can I transcode a file with FFmpeg and read the output file on-the-fly?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mp4, transcode

I have a .M3U8 stream and I can download it and convert it with FFmpeg:
`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i "org_file.m3u8" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4`
However I can't open the output.mp4 file while it is transcoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular MP4 files cannot be played while being transcoded, since the MOOV atom (which is required to parse the file) is written at the end, once the encoding is finished. In many cases it *then* gets moved to the beginning of the file – that's what `-movflags +faststart` does – but you still have to wait for the file to be written once.

Fragmented MP4 (fMP4) files are a special kind of MP4 files that can be read while being written to, see [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18179/525). Use `-movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov` to enable the fragmentation.

MPEG-2 Transport Stream files can be played while being written to, as long as sufficient amount of data has been written. You could try writing the data to a `.ts` file, then waiting a few seconds, and then starting playback.

If you want to write the data in realtime, you have to add the global option `-re`, which makes ffmpeg read the input in realtime and consequently not write faster than what you can play.

Comment: Fragmented MP4s can be played while being written. See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/18177

Answer (score 3):

Using the ISMV format (`-f ismv`) seems to automatically select the right `-movflags` options to be able to read the output file while encoding :

```bash
$ ffmpeg .... -f ismv output.mp4
$ man ffmpeg-formats | grep ismv -B5
           Set the sample rate for libopenmpt to output.  Range is from 1000 to INT_MAX. The value default is 48000.

   mov/mp4/3gp
       Demuxer for Quicktime File Format & ISO/IEC Base Media File Format (ISO/IEC 14496-12 or MPEG-4 Part 12, ISO/IEC 15444-12 or JPEG 2000 Part 12).

       Registered extensions: mov, mp4, m4a, 3gp, 3g2, mj2, psp, m4b, ism, ismv, isma, f4v
--

               ffmpeg -i INPUT -f md5 -

       See also the hash and framemd5 muxers.

   mov, mp4, ismv
       MOV/MP4/ISMV (Smooth Streaming) muxer.

       The mov/mp4/ismv muxer supports fragmentation. Normally, a MOV/MP4 file has all the metadata about all packets stored in one location (written at
--
       -movflags empty_moov
           Write an initial moov atom directly at the start of the file, without describing any samples in it. Generally, an mdat/moov pair is written at
           the start of the file, as a normal MOV/MP4 file, containing only a short portion of the file. With this option set, there is no initial mdat
           atom, and the moov atom only describes the tracks but has a zero duration.

           This option is implicitly set when writing ismv (Smooth Streaming) files.

       -movflags separate_moof
           Write a separate moof (movie fragment) atom for each track. Normally, packets for all tracks are written in a moof atom (which is slightly more
           efficient), but with this option set, the muxer writes one moof/mdat pair for each track, making it easier to separate tracks.

           This option is implicitly set when writing ismv (Smooth Streaming) files.
--
       -movflags negative_cts_offsets
           Enables utilization of version 1 of the CTTS box, in which the CTS offsets can be negative. This enables the initial sample to have DTS/CTS of
           zero, and reduces the need for edit lists for some cases such as video tracks with B-frames. Additionally, eases conformance with the DASH-IF
           interoperability guidelines.

           This option is implicitly set when writing ismv (Smooth Streaming) files.
--

       Example

       Smooth Streaming content can be pushed in real time to a publishing point on IIS with this muxer. Example:
```